# How to show all data and filter one in mongoose and mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to get all the data out of mongo database, but i want to filter one specifically.

What i'm trying to do is. Get someone to click on my portfolio to show them details about what i created. But on left sidebar i want to show other work that i've done. Check pictures and you should understand better.

```
 router.get('/portfolio/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Work.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundWork) {
    console.log(foundWork)

    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render('portfolio', {
        title: 'Portfólio',
        work: foundWork
      });
    }
  });
});
```

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kOPwf.png)

FindById only showing the result of one specific project.

Thanks for your help

EDITED-----------------------------------------------------

So i changed the code to get all data from DB and filtered item that i need by id. I can't parse the data through to ejs. When i console.log data in nodejs i get data. When i console log in ejs i get undefined.

Here is the pic what i get in nodejs.

[Console.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kG7Dc.png)

I noticed when i loop through the filtered item i get all data i need. I dont think it's right to loop through data when i'm onlz parsing one item to ejs.

Comment: what pictures? Please update your question

Comment: Sorry i uploaded picture

Comment: your best bet is to use `.find(` to get all items and then filter out with js `.filter` method separately the item that was clicked and all other items

Comment: I did what you said. It works on javascript side but it doesnt work on ejs side. I get undefined when i consolelog from ejs but when i consolelog in nodejs i get what i need.

Comment: Here is my code:

`code` router.get('/portfolio/:id', function(req, res, next) {
  Work.find({}, function(err, foundWork) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.render('portfolio', {
        title: 'Portfólio',
        work: foundWork,
        findOne: foundWork.filter(work => work._id == req.params.id)
      });
    }
  });
});
`code`

Comment: what is the structure of "foundWork" this response?

Comment: I updated question. Thanks for your help so far

Answer (score 0):

So i figured this out myself.

I did as the user givehug said. It worked but then i had to loop through the filtered items again in ejs despite there is only one item. EJS doesnt know how many items as left in filtered array so i looped through. Got one item out and then i rendered it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a new property to your schema to classify your work. for example,

in your schema:

```
{workType:{type:String}} //either required or no
```

when you post your data, add this property too

```
{workType:"other"} //i just made it up
```

query like this:

```
const other=await Work.find({workType:"other"})
```

now you will get the data that u need.